# All the games started lagging suddenly

Tags: pc, windows, astroneer

Suddenly all the games started lagging , I have tried everything, read everything and its been more than a month now. Installed new windows and even set my system setup to factory settings and installed the game only (nothing other than drivers), emptied my hard drive but nothing worked.

1. Whenever I played a heavy game my system fan would start moving faster and it won't lag and a lot of heat would come out of my pc but now it doesn't heat up whenever I play a heavy game it just lags from start and system never heats up a little and fan moves with regular speed.
2. This has also affected my pc speed so it just runs slower. Even though the startup processes aren't that much.

PC specs:

[image: Intel Extreme Tuning Tool]

[image]

Dedicated Video Memory bothers me. Please help me, I am not very good at these things, I am learning about PC. Even games like Astroneer which shouldn't lag on my PC lag every second. Its like constant lag.

Comment: Did your PC not have a graphics card when you got it (besides intel HD)?

Comment: no , it did't have any nVidia or AMD graphic card but still games were working fine .
I played games like neverwinter without any lag its now I am getting lag

Comment: I think the lack of noise from your system fan and the absence of heat being pushed out is really telling.  You probably need a new fan (at least) and possibly other components are also malfunctioning.  That fact that this lag occurs in *all games* tells us it's most likely *not a problem with the game(s)*

Comment: If your PC is lagging in all aspects, this isn't a gaming issue; there's something wrong with your computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about generic computer issues, not anything specific to gaming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As they state in the minimum system requirements for Astroneer, your system is right on the edge of its possibilities:

> Astroneer minimum system requirements:
>
> - OS: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10
> - Processor: X64 Dual Core CPU, 2+ GHz
> - Memory: 4 GB RAM
> - Graphics: Discrete Non Mobile GPU with 1 GB Ram
> - DirectX: Version 11
> - Storage: 2 GB available space
> - Sound card: Any

And the recommended system requirements:

> Astroneer recommended system requirements:
>
> - OS: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10
> - Processor: X64 Quad Core CPU, 3+ GHz
> - Memory: 8 GB RAM
> - Graphics: Discrete GPU with 2 GB RAM
> - DirectX: Version 11
> - Storage: 4 GB available space
> - Sound card: Any

Source: [Astroneer Steam Shop Page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/361420/ASTRONEER/)

As you can see they recommend a CPU with at least four cores (yours has two) and 3 GHz and higher clock ratios.

---

So how does this help you? I'd recommend that you monitor your system during execution of a game like Astroneer to see if its under heavy load or not. You could simply do this with the Windows Task Manager opened and look at the CPU and RAM utilization.

Another thing you pointed out is the absence of heat during heavy workload, which could be caused by malfunctioning components. Also make sure your system fans are working properly that your CPU doesn't expect thermal throttling (happens if your CPU is to hot because of bad cooling and minimizes the clock ratio → less performance). [Piriform Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy) is a good tool to monitor system temperatures.

Maybe you consider to upgrade your system in the near future, which would eliminate most of this problems. But that's not an answer right? :) So, if you could do some of the tests mentioned above and provide more information about your systems behavior, it will be much easier for us to help you.

---

**Edit**

Due to the comments below, you got a heat problem. Check your fans and especially your CPU cooler. Remove dust if there is any to get a good airflow. If all of your fans work and nothing blocks the airflow inside the computer the temperatures should decrease and throttling won't occur.

Comment: But the thing is All the other games don't work as well.

Comment: And Why my dedicated video memory is 32mb It should be like 128 or 256 mb

Comment: Neverwinter game which is MMO RPG worked fine on my pc

Comment: hmm, okay. However the graphics performance of your Intel HD Graphics 4000 isn't the best but should perform better. Are the drivers up to date? Did you look at your utilization and temperatures?

Comment: normal temprature in 70-90

Comment: When I play game the thermal throttling turns yes in extreme tuning intel utility and temprature in very muc

Comment: Well, that's bad. As soon as your CPU throttles because of too high temperatures your performance decreases extremely. Check if your CPU cooler works as it should and try to get the temperatures on a lower level. Is it possible to swap the CPU cooler to a more powerful one?

Comment: Normal idle temperatures shouldn't be above 50°C. On the manufacturers website, 90°C  is defined as the max temperature of the CPU: 
 https://ark.intel.com/de/products/71465/Intel-Core-i3-3120M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_50-GHz